# Get "The system cannot find the file specified." when I change directories at Windows 10 command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, runtime-error, stdout, io-redirection

Why do I get the "The system cannot find the file specified." error message when I use the following sequence of commands at the Windows 10 Command Prompt?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1415]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd \Users\Public

C:\Users\Public>echo.>junk.txt

C:\Users\Public>cd Documents

C:\Users\Public\Documents>echo.>junk.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\Public\Documents>
```

I get the same results for all users, not just "Public".  I get the same results when executed with "administrator" privileges or not.

Please help; I've spent hours searching the web and stack**overflow** for an answer and haven't found one.

Comment: Try changing the file name. Try adding spaces.

Comment: Please note the before and after: before the "cd documents" there is no error and after the "cd documents" the error occurs. Name changes make no difference; neither do spaces.

Comment: Note this isnt actually MS-DOS. I started using real MS-DOS in like 1989.

Comment: Sometimes spaces would matter. It's also conceivable there's some weird path issue. It's kinda hard to troubleshoot this way. Trying variations help to eliminate potential issues.

Comment: @shawnt00 You're right about calling it MS-DOS, It's actually the command prompt from Windows 10 which is an emulation of MS-DOS.

Comment: I know. I do happen to know a thing or two about this stuff.

Comment: Give me a break! I'm new to this forum, but I've been using MS-Dos longer than you have. It's not a simple syntax problem, tell me what you need as proof.

Comment: I have suspected an access permissions problem and have looked at my permissions for all directories in both paths and I have all permissions including administrator.

Comment: Then start debugging. Can you see the file in the directory? Can you delete the file? Does it break only when executed in that order?

Comment: "Other command delimiters are available but have buggy side effects, for example Echo. will search for a file named "echo" in the current directory, if such a file is found that will raise an error. If the 'echo' file does not exist then the command does work, but this still makes Echo. slightly slower than echo:"